# Chaining jquery functions - Beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the name and ID of an element when a radio button is clicked on. To avoid duplicating the selector, I attempted to set it up like this:

```
$( "#selectOther" ).click(function() {
    $( "[field=primaryInput]" ).attr('id', "modifiedId", function() {
        $(this).attr('name', "modifiedName");
        if ($(this).attr('visible') == "False") {
            $(this).slideDown('fast');
            $(this).attr("visible", "True");
        }
    });
});
```

However, it isn't working. It seems that the ID is changed, but the Name is not, nor is the rest of the function executed. Could someone help me understand how to express this correctly?

Here's a [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pe9ss2qx/).

EDIT: In my final case I will have a couple of buttons that reveal the field if it is hidden, and others that will hide it if it is visible. That is why I am not using `.slideToggle()`

Comment: Did you bother reading the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)?

Comment: `attr()` takes one or two arguments, either an attribute id (getter) or an attribute id and a value (setter).  Not sure what you're expecting to happen with it.  You could just do something like: `var thing = $("[field=primaryInput]"); thing.attr('id', "modifiedId"); thing.attr('name', "modifiedName"); ... `

Comment: Note that changing the `id` attributes of elements dynamically is not a very good idea. They are intended to be immutable. If you need to know about a change to an element use literally any other attribute. Also note that `field` and `visible` are not valid attributes and will mean your HTML is invalid. To store custom meta data with an element, use a `data-*` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess it's probably best to have separate elements. I thought I'd seen examples of this working this way before, and was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6526ms4/1/):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  $('input[data="primaryInput"]')
    .prop('id', this.id)
    .prop('name', this.name)
    .val(this.value)
    .css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

Number of points:

1. You didn't set an external resource (namely jQuery) in your fiddle - so you wouldn't ever get jQuery functions to execute
2. Use the `data` attribute for custom attributes. You can access them the way I have done or by selecting the `$(element).data('field')`

This example might help you understand how chaining works. One other piece of advise is that chaining only works if the method invoked next receives the same element the previous method returns. If it ever changes, you can use [end()](https://api.jquery.com/end/) to get the previous state.

Comment: Note that you can greatly simplify the code with `this.id`, `this.name` and `this.value` instead of invoking jQuery three times for trivial data.

Comment: @Adam Starrh Note the use of prop instead of attr, see [prop-vs-attr](/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Thank you! I guess what I was really after was the sliding aspect. ie. If the field is hidden, slide down, if it is visible, slide up. Good to learn about  `.prop` though!

Comment: Welcome - slide effects are easy enough to add on